# Why isn't setting classes for my DataTables doing anything?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

EDIT:

Fiddle which recreates issue:
https://jsfiddle.net/w8pkjek2/3/
[My first time using fiddle...lemme know if i did it wrong.]

---

I am trying to add cell-borders to my table, which uses DataTables.net.  I am able to adjust my table via my dataTable() call, but not using the css.  I have this code in my header:

```
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.5/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.5/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

and this code in my body:

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#my-table').dataTable({
                "paging": false,
                "info": false,
                "searching": false
            });
        });
    </script>
    <table id="my-table" class="cell-border" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Header 1</th>
            <th>Header 2</th>
            <th>Header 3</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Cell 1</td>
            <td>Cell 2</td>
            <td>Cell 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cell 4</td>
            <td>Cell 5</td>
            <td>Cell 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cell 7</td>
            <td>Cell 8</td>
            <td>Cell 9</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cell 10</td>
            <td>Cell 11</td>
            <td>Cell 12</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I have confirmed that my `paging`, `info`, and `searching` parameters are having an effect (commenting those lines out has them appear).  I have confirmed that my `jquery.dataTables.min.js` script is being read (commenting it out along with the `paging`, `info`, and `searching` has them not appear).

Based on this, I am assuming `jquery.dataTables.min.css` is being read.  My table has the class `"cell-border"`, but there is no borders around any of my tables cells.  I have also tried `"row-border"`.

Why is my table not reacting to `jquery.dataTables.min.css` for the class of `"cell-border"`?

Comment: Have you investigated via the browser developer tools to see what CSS rules apply to the various table elements?

Comment: Does your table also have the `.dataTable` class? The rules for `.cell-border` are dependent upon the table having both.

Comment: @Pointy I had not. But I did now. I get error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {` on line 1 of `jquery.dataTables.min.css`.

Comment: @Adrift I believe so, unless I am misunderstanding.  I was under the impression that my 2nd script, right below the .css call, was getting the class.  (And I have tried calling those scripts in opposite orders.)

Comment: @Evorlor: I only said that because I didn't see it in your HTML. Adding a demo would help.

Comment: @Adrift demo added to question

Comment: Why do my web questions always get downvoted? Just the web development community, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to include jquery.dataTables.min.css as a stylesheet instead of a script.

This works for me:

```
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.5/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"  rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: jquery.dataTables.min.css is a css file, not a js script file. script tag is used to include js files, not css files. For css files use link tag instead.